# @id parameter is not working in xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt

```xml
<xsl:template match="tref[@id=($exsampleXml//Topic/Object[./IncludeInWeb = 'false' and @id = ./ID]/ID)][1]"/>
```

Hi how can we give `@id` as the parameter of the code snippet? (`@id = ./ID` in the above snippet)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to compare `@id` against the `ID` in the predicate on `Object`. Just this should work:

```xml
<xsl:template match="tref[@id=$exsampleXml//Topic/Object[IncludeInWeb='false']/ID]"/>
```

Note: also removed the last positional predicate `[1]`. You can put it back if you really only want to match the first `tref`.